# How to get the contents of a pre tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I get a value from a 'pre' tag?

`<pre>43453453</pre>`

For example, I know how to get the tag, but how do I get the content inside it?

```
var x = documentGetElementsByTagName("pre");
```

I tried using innerHTML, and textContent, but those didn't work for me.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of nodes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` will return a NodeList and not first element. So you will have to loop over list and fetch manually.

If its just one element, you can even look into `document.querySelector`. This will give you first element of given selector

```js
var _html = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(_html)

var _query = document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML
console.log(_query)
```

```html
<pre>43453453</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of interest, why do you use the underscore in front of the variable names?

Comment: Just a convention. `_` before variable name can be used to depict `private variable`. Similarly, all caps mean `constant/global variable`